# how can I get path of file from input api

Tags: javascript, html

hy users

I try to get the path of a file via html5 js

I try:

```
jQuery("#pfad").change(function(evt){
   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     alert(files[i].path); 
    }
```

but path isn't a attribute of this file object....
what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the full file path due to security limitations. However you can read the name of the file:

```
jQuery("#pfad").change(function (evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        console.log(files[i].name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers dont allow to get the full file path on client side. But in case of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox you can get the path by:

```
jQuery("#pfad").change(function(evt){
    var path = $(this).val();
    alert(path);
}
```

I tested it on both of these browsers.

Comment: Just to mention that returned path is not the real one, but "fake".

Comment: yeh it is the temporary path which browser used to put the selected file for posting it to server. But still the path is importrant.

Comment: No, it's not temporary, it's just fake. Chrome will give something like "C:\fakepath\filename.jpg", and Firefox will return the name property, not even a path.

Comment: But you can find the file on that path at the time of posting when browser is temporary using it??